# Whay i am not able to merge ext4 partition with unalloted space?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, ubuntu-one, boot-partition

I had windows and ubuntu os on my machine. I have deleted the windows os and free up 68 gb.
But still i cant resize the partition, when i click on resize/move it gives max and min as same which means i cant expand my partition.
I have made swap off.
But still no sucess.
Any suggestions ot if i am making mistake somewhere.

Comment: I am doing by booting from a live cd

Comment: And i am using gparted utility to do the partition

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the unallocated space exist to the left or right to your ext4 partition with which you want to join. Like -

[image]

From your question I guess you want to merge unallocated space with your root disk. It is a bit dangerous step. So, in that case, you should have a backup of your data.

To move the unallocated space to specific disk -

- Go to the adjacent disk to the unallocated space and choose the move/resize option in GParted, and then move the unallocated space towards the disk you want to merge.